# Subcount's as fields in a mysql query

Tags: mysql

For a statistics application, with a table structure as such:

```
unique_id | browser_family | os | date_time | js_enabled | flash_enabled | non_binary_field

1           firefox          w7    ...         1            0              yes
2           chrome           w7    ...         1            1              no
3           ie9              wx    ...         0            0              yes
```

So, I'd like to perform a query with where clauses on any fields, and have it give me counts of js_enabled=1, flash_enabled =0, non_binary_field = 'yes' for those criteria (say `os` = 'w7' and date(`date_time`) = '01-08-2012').

The result would be:

```
count(js_enabled=1) | count(flash_enabled=1) | count(non_binary_field='yes')
2                     1                        1
```

Is this possible in a single query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select sum(js_enabled=1),
       sum(flash_enabled=1),
       sum(non_binary_field='yes')
from your_table
where `os` = 'w7'
and date(`date_time`) = '2012-08-01'
```

Comment: sounds simple! let me try it.

Comment: don't think it will work. sum takes column_name as a parameter. js_enabled isn't a column_name in source table

Comment: this will work :)  I used it a lot. Giving a boolean operation to `sum` will add up the `true` cases.

Comment: @juergend Could you please point to any doc saying that sum can take boolean operator?

Comment: Cool! Just found that mysql has this feature. T-SQL doesn't! +1

Comment: To make this better, don't wrap the `date_time` column in a function. Keep the query sargable (able to utilize indexes) and use `AND date_time >= '2012-08-01 00:00:00' AND date_time < '2012-08-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Comment: Yeah, that's nuts! Makes sense since MySQL must use 1's as true, I never thought of trying it!

Answer (score 0):

Each field can be filled by a separate subquery:

```
select
(select count(js_enabled) from yourtable where js_enabled=1),
(select count(flash_enabled) from yourtable where flash_enabled=1),
(select count(non_binary_field) from yourtable where non_binary_field='yes')
```